# Add condition to Doctrine QueryBuilder's where-in-clause

Tags: doctrine-orm, api-platform.com, where-in

I'm using API-Platform and need to select on certain conditions. I'm using extensions to do so, which is passed an Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder.

In general that works fine, but in this case I'm struggling to modify the sub-query, in the `WHERE id IN(sub-query)` clause.

This is the received query as a string (note that it's passed as a QueryBuilder object, not a string):

```
SELECT o 
FROM App\\Entity\\Employee o 
WHERE o.organization IN(
    SELECT id_a1 
    FROM App\\Entity\\Organization id_a1 
    WHERE id_a1.id = :id_p1
)
```

What I need to add to the subquery is one more condition to the where-clause, so it will become:

```
...
IN(
    SELECT id_a1 
    FROM App\\Entity\\Organization id_a1 
    WHERE id_a1.id = :id_p1 AND id_a1.owner = :owner
)
```

I need help to solve how to get receive just the sub-query and modify this object. I assume it's a QueryBuilder or some other object that lives in the original QueryBuilder object.

**Edit**:
This is a hack I made, but it can easily break.

```php
$query = $this->getQueryBuilder();    

$where = $query->getDQLPart('where');    
$query->resetDQLPart("where");    

$squery = $this->getQueryBuilder()    
->getEntityManager()    
->createQueryBuilder();    

$param = $query->getParameters()[0];    

$squery->select("org")    
->from(\App\Entity\Organization::class, "org")    
->where("org.owner = :owner")    
->andWhere(sprintf("org.id = :%s", $param->getName()));    

$field = sprintf("%s.organization", $query->getRootAlias());    

foreach($where->getParts() as $key => $value) {    
    if (strpos($value->getName(), $field) !== false) {    
        $query->where(    
        $query->expr()->in(    
            $field,    
            $squery->getDQL()    
        )    
        );    
        $query->setParameter(":owner", $this->security->getUser());    
    }    
}
```

Comment: I might be missing some context and be completely wrong, but can't you solve this using a `join`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you suggestion. The problem is that the `query` in the `QueryBuilder` is already given as described, with the sub-query. I could do an additional join, but I would rather like to alter the original sub-query to limit access instead of using more resources.